# Undefined variables in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Here is a JavaScript example from *Eloquent JavaScript*:

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}
```

At the very beginning "start" and "goal" in line 3 are not defined. Why does the code not immediately return a result like "undefined" or "ReferenceError: ... is not defined"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 3 is just part of the function definition. It is not being executed. The second to last line is the one that kicks off the execution. When it is called, the values 1 and "1" are assigned to parameters start and history. goal is referencing the outer function's parameter. This is populated when the outer function is called.

Answer (score 0):

start and goal are the arguments to the find and findSequence functions in lines 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

They don't result in errors because by line 3 they are both defined.  In JavaScript function parameters are implicitly defined as local variables inside of that function.  That is why `start` is defined and initialized with the value that was passed as the first argument when `find` is invoked.  In the same way `goal` was defined on line 1 in the `function` statement that created the `findSequence` function.  `goal` is accessible inside of the `find` function via [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29).  It is a little more complicated but for the purpose of this example, closure means that when a function is defined inside of another function it has access to variables that belong to the parent functions scope.

If you want to learn more about closures (which would be a good idea if you will be writing a lot of JavaScript code) checkout [Closing the book on JavaScript Closures](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Closing_The_Book_On_Javascript_Closures), it is a pretty good article about closures. I haven't read the whole thing but [this FAQ](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) seems to be quite good too.

Stuart Langridge gave a great lecture called *Secrets of JavaScript Closures* at the Fronteers Conference '08: [Part 1](http://vimeo.com/1967261), [Part 2](http://vimeo.com/1966626)